# EF Mapping Entities in different namespaces

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, mapping, entities

I have split my application out into the following layers below which consists of modules from the service layer down.

UI - MVC

Module1.Service

Module1.Model - POCO Entities

Module1.Repository.EF - Module1 EDMX

Module2.Service

Module2.Model - POCO Entities

Module2.Repository.EF - Module2 EDMX

Common.Model - Base Poco Entities. Both modules models would inherit these base entities.

My poco entities are inside a model project and they just consist of properties. The edmx diagram is inside the repository.EF project.

The common.model project will have base entities that both the modules poco entities will inherit from. The problem I have in my edmx diagram is that I need to use multiple namespaces. Module1.Model and Common.Model. Plus I have also separated out the entities within both projects into different folders which means I have to use x number of different namespaces.

The current edmx diagram only has one namespace textbox but I need to use several. Is there a way using the xml part or by code first to map the entities from different namespaces?

I'm sure other people must have run into this problem before. Otherwise I will have to remove the common.model project and have the same entities in each module which means duplicating everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that using code first fixes this issue. I can use a common model project to keep my base models in and then in the modules model projects they can inherit from the base models.